# Can different threads share a stack (win32)?

Tags: windows, multithreading, assembly, x86, operating-system

By default, different threads also have different stacks. Is it possible to make them share the same thread? For example: I want to call a function in thread A, but the argument for that function call was pushed onto the stack in thread B. Since those threads do not share a stack, the function call in thread A will fail.

example code:

```
section .bss
lock resb 1

section .text
..start:
...                ;push CreateThread parameters for thread2
call [CreateThread]
loop:
cmp lock, 1
jnz loop
call [exampleFunc]
ret

thread2:
push exampleFuncParam
mov al, 1
mov [lock], al
ret
```

Comment: No, but you can pass a pointer to a value on another thread's stack since stacks live in memory and threads share memory.

Comment: @Jester How would I find out at which address the value on the stack is located? In thread2 the pointer to the address of the value would be the esp, but I can't directly access the esp of thread2 in thread1, can I? So I would need to save the esp in a global variable but that seems like a very laborious workaround. Is there another way?

Comment: Sounds like your real problem is to figure out some worker-thread synchronization
 mechanism for one thread to be able to let another thread know it should do something.  The fact that you have data in memory in one thread's stack isn't the hard part - you can `lea` a pointer into a register, and store that pointer into a shared variable that's part of you inter-thread communication mechanism for threads to find work to do.  Or you can of course just start a new thread with whatever parameters you want passed to it.

Comment: You could pass the address/instance/whatever in a message over a producer-consumer queue.  You could pass it in a constructor argument.  You could pass it as part of a 'CreateThread()' pointer argument.  Pick your poison:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stacks are just part of memory and threads share their entire address space.

Threads have their own stacks the way hotel guests have their own rooms, except all the doors are unlocked. Each guest is generally expected to use and stay in their own room, but nothing stops them from walking into another person's room and messing with the other person's stuff. If invited in, this is completely acceptable.

You can safely access an object on one thread's stack from another thread so long as the access would be thread safe if the object wasn't on the stack and you ensure the stack frame continues to exist until the object is no longer accessed.